# Exclusion constraints not taking effect in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Here is the code:

```
testdb=# CREATE TABLE COMPANY7(
testdb(#    ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
testdb(#    NAME           TEXT ,
testdb(#    AGE            INT   ,
testdb(#    ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
testdb(#    SALARY         REAL,
testdb(#    EXCLUDE USING gist
testdb(#    (NAME WITH =,
testdb(#    AGE WITH <>)
testdb(# );
CREATE TABLE
testdb=#  INSERT INTO COMPANY7 VALUES(1, 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 );
INSERT 0 1
testdb=#  INSERT INTO COMPANY7 VALUES(2, 'Paul', 32, 'Texas', 20000.00 );
INSERT 0 1
testdb=#  INSERT INTO COMPANY7 VALUES(3, 'Allen', 42, 'California', 20000.00 );
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# table company7
testdb-# ;
 id | name  | age |                      address                       | salary
----+-------+-----+----------------------------------------------------+--------
  1 | Paul  |  32 | California                                         |  20000
  2 | Paul  |  32 | Texas                                              |  20000
  3 | Allen |  42 | California                                         |  20000
(3 rows)
```

Clearly both constraints are violated, but there is no error, why?

PostgreSQL version 9.4.4

Tested on Ubuntu 15.04 and OS X 10.10

Comment: The constraint is not violated. Could you explain what you're expecting it to do?

Comment: Well, the name "Paul" appeared twice, which is a violation, right?

Comment: No, like @Sathish said, the exclusion constraint means that you cannot have two rows where the names are equal and the ages are not equal. If both are equal, it's allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   EXCLUDE USING gist
   (NAME WITH =,
   AGE WITH <>)
```

Which means same Name and Different Age not Allowed.

I tried like this it show error

```
   INSERT INTO appsetup.COMPANY7 VALUES(4, 'Paul', 42, 'California', 20000.00 );
```

**ERROR**

```
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "company7_name_age_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (name, age)=(Paul, 42) conflicts with existing key (name, age)=(Paul, 32).
```